# Incorrect message_count from RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I have some actions that consume lots of resources, so I decided to queue them. The functionality works fine, but I wanted to show the number of messages somewhere on the client.

It is done within `GraphQL subscription`, so I get the current status every 10s. The problem is after using `queue_declare()` from `Kombu`.

```py
from kombu import Connection

def get_queue_message_count(channel, queue: str) -> int:
    _1, message_count, _2 = channel.queue_declare(
        queue=queue, passive=True, durable=True, auto_delete=False, arguments={"x-max-priority": 10}
    )
    print(f"{queue}: {message_count}")

    return message_count


async def generate_queue_status(_obj, _info) -> AsyncGenerator[Dict[str, Any], None]:
    with Connection(app_config.queue.broker) as connection:
        with connection.channel() as channel:
            while True:
                message_count = get_queue_message_count(channel, "actions")
                yield {"error": None, "messages": message_count}
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

For the 1st time I get correct number, for the rest it is 0 even though the total number of messages in the management tool is greater than 0:

[image: Queue status]

Comment: i think if messages in queue are processed quickly then they don't appear in count. I have observed same in my kibana visualisation. Can you stop your consumer of the queue and check. Just a thought

Comment: I will do some additional debugging, but it is strange, that management tool shows 8 and it decreases one by one in around 2 minutes, but my code returns 0 in meantime